# about yii2 framework and rest api

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, crud, postman

hello i try to make a rest api for first time and i use postman to show result but there is an error when i use POST the error is { "message": "Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET, HEAD.",}

this is my controller

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class TestController extends ActiveController{
public $modelClass='backend\models\test';
}
```

and this is the main in config folder

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
'id' => 'app-backend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'modules' => [
     'api' => [
        'class' => 'backend\modules\api\Api',                     
    ],
  ],
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
        'name' => 'advanced-backend',
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],

    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => FALSE,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'test'],
        ],
    ], 


],
'params' => $params,
  ];
```

Comment: Which URL youre trying to access?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/advanced/backend/web/test

Comment: And you want to access `actionCreate()`, right?,

Comment: yes i want to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set param `pluralize` to `false`:

```
   'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'test',
            'pluralize' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Or try to access it by URL: `127.0.0.1/advanced/backend/web/tests`.

More about `pluralize` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$pluralize-detail).